# how to align the content of the paragraph so that it looks perfect in mobile device

Tags: html, css

> I want to justify my content. But when I am using "text-align:
>   justify", there is some space between words. Space between should be eliminated.

[image]

```
 .p
   { 
    text-align : justify;
   }
```

Comment: That's what justify does

Comment: *justify
The inline contents are justified. Text should be spaced to line up its left and right edges to the left and right edges of the line box, except for the last line.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: provide me better solution.... for the alignment

Comment: "provide me better solution.... for the alignment" - how exactly would you like the text to be aligned?

Comment: *better* is opinion based. Describe what is *better* for you because for me what you have is already the best

Comment: extra space should not be there,but it should be justified

Comment: so you want the extra space added inbetween the letters of the words? That would be the only solution I got in mind. The space needs to be entered somewhere to justify...

Comment: You can't have both non-extra space AND justify. You need to choose.

Comment: ya, i understand.....

Answer (score 3):

That's how justifying works, especially when there are very long words - as you cannot fit more than two or three words in a line with them, you need to space out those lines and other lines  around to make up for it.

"Worcestershire" cannot fit in one line with "young people in", and adding "wanted" will break the line - hence the spacing to force justification.

If you want to justify the lines, your only option to make this look better is increase the width of the element or decrease the font size.

Comment: but this is also not perfect way......as the device size will change.....it will can create same problem

Comment: @annaya you have to decide what is more important - justifying or block width. On very small screens things will always look bad, you have to decide what your target minimum size and work with that. Another option is a smaller font - with its own drawbacks.